# How to delinking an linked account from my Alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have perform a/c linking with an external service with my Alexa skill, which works fine. I wanted to remove this a/c linking and link with another a/c. If I disable the skill, it enables the a/c linking option but when I try to link, it seems to take the last a/c session and gets liked with previous a/c without asking for credential details.

Can someone let me know what is the way to remove my a/c linking?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the a/c app first to remove any credentials. Then disable the skill. Then start the whole process again

Comment: Thanks German for your response, appreciate it. I was doing it from web on a browser. Any suggestion how it can be done there? I have already tried logout and login back option but didn't help.

Comment: What's the a/c app?

Comment: Re-enabling the skill will remove the last linked account and will ask for the new login credentials. This should work in iOS, android and web apps. Is 
 you external service relying on any cookies that might cause the previously logged in user to login again?. Trying clearing the cache or re-install the app as @German suggested.

Comment: What does it mean by exactly a/c app? There is no such option to logout/uninstall/unlink account.